# Icon not appearing in Xcode archive?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, icons

My app icon isn't appearing in Xcode archives. I have them set in the plist and they are showing on the simulator, on the device and in the project settings. See the picture below:

[image]

How can i fix this? Im using the 4.3.1 by the way.

Thanks...

Comment: Off-Topic: Nice you're creating a Cycle Hire app. I got one of those in the App Store too :)

Comment: did you add the icon file to your project -> target ?

Comment: yeah i'm making a cycle hire app! which is yours? Yeah I did add it to the target if that's dragging it from the resources directory to the little placeholders.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Delete all versions of your app from your device.

In Xcode, do "Command+Option+Shift+K" and say yes.

Try to archive again?

Btw, I don't think Default.png and Default@2x.png should be in your icon list.

Comment: Thanks for the help but still no luck! Tried everything you said. I'm lost with this, such a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add [small icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW10) and an [App Store icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) to the project.

Comment: Never had to do that with my previous apps so don't think it's that.

Comment: @Adam Waite, yeah, right, it might be working before, but now my recommendation would be to add all the icons at once (and i forgot to mention  iTunesArtwork which might be critical), you can use some tool to generate all the icons automatically from the hi-def source. Haven't you update Xcode recently ?

Comment: i just used a different mac and it worked. Same version of Xcode. I think that anything to do with archiving/provisioning/codesigning all sucks in Xcode to be honest.

Comment: @Adam Waite now that's interesting, would be great if you try to play a little with a .xcodeproj content (don't forget to make a safe reserve copy!). deleting xcuserdata folder on both machines might give you something. As far as i can see simple Edit Scheme - Archive creates a new section at schemename.xcscheme file, maybe that section is required and missing as your username on another machine is not the same ? SO trying to go to Edit Scheme and select Archive would be also something to try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget on correct icon naming. And the Default.png shouldn't be in the .plist.
Also check the target of the icon files.

Icon.png
Icon@2x.png
Icon-72.png

In Xcode press

1. Command+Shift+K and press Yes.
2. Command+Shift+Alt+K and press Yes.
3. The try building, running and Archiving.

Comment: Tried all of your suggestion but none have sorted it. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your iTunesArtwork as Item 6 in Icon Files in your plist.  Apparently, this is where the Archive window get its image from.